# Restrict double click on delete in minicart in magento 2

Tags: magento2, jquery, mini-cart

In minicart of magento 2, when click on delete icon, confirm popup is open. after confirm, it take sometime time to delete. till the time we are able to click multiple time. and popup will come multiple time.

How to stop multiple time click on delete button?

```
 events['click ' + this.options.button.remove] =  function (event) {
             event.stopPropagation();
            confirm({

                content: self.options.confirmMessage,
                actions: {
                    /** @inheritdoc */
                    confirm: function () {
                        self._removeItem($(event.currentTarget));
                        location.reload();

                    },


                    /** @inheritdoc */
                    always: function (e) {
                        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by extending magento sidebar widget using mixin.

For example you can create a custom module and following files.

> view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/sidebar': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/sidebar-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

> view/frontend/web/js/sidebar-mixin.js

```
define(['jquery', 'mage/cookies'], function($) {
    return function(targetWidget) {
        $.widget('mage.sidebar', targetWidget, {
            _ajax: function (url, data, elem, callback) {
                $.extend(data, {
                    'form_key': $.mage.cookies.get('form_key')
                });

                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data: data,
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    context: this,
                    showLoader: true,

                    /** @inheritdoc */
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        elem.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    },

                    /** @inheritdoc */
                    complete: function () {
                        elem.attr('disabled', null);
                    }
                })
                    .done(function (response) {
                        var msg;

                        if (response.success) {
                            callback.call(this, elem, response);
                        } else {
                            msg = response['error_message'];

                            if (msg) {
                                alert({
                                    content: msg
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .fail(function (error) {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                    });
            }
        });

        return $.mage.sidebar;
    }
})
```

Here you can copy the entire _ajax function from original file "vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar.js" to above newly created file. What you can do is just add **showLoader: true** in ajax call so that user wont be able to click anywhere else during this ajax call completion.

Repalce Vendor and Module name with your newly created vendor/extension name.

Hope this helps.